# meaning of "sweets"- dessert, candy, or?

Tags: vocabulary

The following is from a travel guideboook. I'm particularly curious about the meaning of "sweets." In the context of a coffee house, it is unlikely to refer to candy or dessert. What could it mean?

> The 1369 Coffee House is... Both branches serve mostly caffeine drinks and **sweets** – with sandwiches at lunch.

I speculate **sweets** here refers to cakes, cookies, etc. But this sense of **sweets** is not found in the dictionary.

---

(Taken from the comments)

The whole passage is as follows:

> The 1369 Coffee House is as community-based as Starbucks is corporate. The original Inman Square branch has a more interesting cross section of ages and ethnicities but Central Square has sidewalk seating. Both branches serve mostly caffeine drinks and **sweets** – with sandwiches at lunch. This is from an Eyewitness Travel Guide.

Comment: it is pointless to speculate what **sweets** means without a little more context. Could you please provide a reference for the quote (ideally a link), or at least specify what country the coffee shop is in, and the nationality of the author?

Comment: Just guessing, but, at a coffee house (in the US), I would regard “sweets” as something like [coffee cake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHWZC.jpg), donuts, muffins, or [cinnamon rolls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aguVV.jpg).

Comment: @J.R.  I hold the same opinion as you do. However, this sense of sweet does not seem to be found in the dictionary.

Comment: @JavaLatte  The whole passage is as follows: The 1369 Coffee House is as community-based as Starbucks is corporate. The original Inman Square branch has a more interesting cross section of ages and
ethnicities but Central Square has sidewalk seating. Both branches serve mostly caffeine drinks and sweets – with sandwiches at lunch. This is from an Eyewitness Travel Guide.

Comment: You are either overthinking it, or not consulting enough dictionaries. [**sweet** (*noun*)](http://wordnik.com/words/sweet) a confection made from sugar or high in sugar content; a food eaten for dessert; sweet dishes served at table such as puddings or tarts; a food rich in sugar.

Comment: @J.R. Does "confection" mean the same as "candy"?

Comment: @Apollyon What do you find when you look up "confection" in your dictionary?

Comment: In England, sweets are things like haribos, whereas cakes and tarts are just that. America uses 'candy' for our 'sweets'.

Comment: @Apollyon - Who cares what “confection” means? Which part of this is unclear to you: **A food rich in sugar**.

Comment: @marcellothearcane sweet can also be used as a synonym of desert in British English, along with pudding and afters. Sweets could be used to mean various sweet course dishes.

Comment: @marcellothearcane   Do you think "sweets" in the quoted passage refers to things like haribos? That's unlikely, isn't it?

Comment: @Sarriesfan But in the context of a coffee house, where people go for afternoon tea, isn't it odd to interpret "sweets" as "desserts"?

Comment: @Apollyon, afternoon tea always comes with scones, small cakes, eclairs as well as finger cut sandwiches. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3c/Tea_at_the_Rittenhouse_Hotel.jpg/480px-Tea_at_the_Rittenhouse_Hotel.jpg

Comment: @Apollyon yes, not likely at all. I was merely pointing it out for interest in differences between AmE and BrE.

Comment: @Sarriesfan What does your nice bit of information have to do with the thread? Do you think "sweets" in the quoted passage refers to desserts?

Comment: @Apollyon, it has to do with the comment that marcellothearcne makes that sweets in British English only refers to haribo type things, my comment is that it can refer to desert courses.

Comment: @Sarriesfan Do you think the use of "sweets" in the original quoted passage is natural?

Comment: @Apollyon, without further information I cannot tell, buts that why I did not address my comment to the thread in general but to marcellothearcnes comment.

Comment: @J.R. Do you think it's natural for "a box of sweets" to refer to a box of sweet foods such as cookies?

Comment: @Apollyon - I think you're asking too many questions in the comments and furnishing too few details in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I found several definitions of the word "sweets", and I think they fit well to the context.

As a personal observation, I happened to enter places called "coffee shops", just to be surprised by their offer:

- large variety of coffee drinks;
- large variety of tea-based and tea-like drinks;
- **large variety of pies, cookies, cakes**;
- others (maybe, I never intended to make an extensive research on this topic).

---

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candy)

> Candy, also called **sweets** or lollies, is a confection that features sugar as a principal ingredient.

---

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sweet)

> **sweet** (n.) = something that is sweet to the taste, such as
>   a food (such as a candy or preserve); having a high sugar content fill up on sweets; British : dessert, hard candy

---

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sweet)

> **sweet** (n.)
>
> 1. (British) A small shaped piece of confectionery made with sugar.
>
>    - a bag of sweets
> 2. (British) A sweet dish forming a course of a meal; a pudding or dessert.

---

[Cambridge Dictionaries](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sweets)

> **sweets** (*plural noun*) = sweet food, such as candy or cake
>
> - Rosie tries to avoid sweets.

Answer (score -5):

It is very easy. In British English, we use the word "sweets". In American English, we use the word "cookies" in place of "sweets" in British.
We use the "desserts" as a course meal like something sweet and full of sugar.

Comment: Cookies is not the same thing as sweets.